# when and how the socratic badge is calculated?

Tags: support, badges

I have tried to be serious in my persuance of the socratic badge, for this I need to ask 100 relevant and useful questions, that have not been already asked.

[image]

I keep monitoring my progress as you can see on the picture below.

Lots of my questions are related to topics that I am current working on, rather than from studies.

Yesterday I asked 2 questions, both have been upvoted, and I have not seen my socratic count go from 41 to 42.

Have I made any mistake?

It might be that I am wrong, as you know, we all have imperfect senses, but I believe I should have 42 instead of 41.

Is it because one of my questions was marked as duplicated?

If so, I would say I had 2 questions yesterday with upvotes, and the question with the duplicate was not 100% duplicated and in my view relevat, at least to my purposes.

[How to remove the WITH ENCRYPTION from the code of the procedure - via T-SQL [duplicate]](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115056/how-to-remove-the-with-encryption-from-the-code-of-the-procedure-via-t-sql)

I was very well answered by [spaguettidba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3020/spaghettidba)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ...for this I need to ask 100 relevant and useful questions...
>   Yesterday I asked 2 questions, both have been upvoted, and I have not seen my socratic count go from 41 to 42.

[image]
[image]

As the image above shows, it is the number of separate **days**, not the number of questions that is important for this badge.

> the duplicate was not 100% duplicated

A question does not need to be an *exact* duplicate to be [closed for that reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled). A key test is whether the question has essentially, or substantially, the same answer.

The answer you received addresses your specific question, so it is only right that you accepted it. However, people searching the site in the future are more likely to be interested in the more general answer, so it makes sense to have that as the 'duplicate'.

The point is probably moot since the status of this question does not affect your badge progress, but I thought I should address that point anyway.